# MySQL query to get next month's employee jubilees

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query to get list of Milestone achievers (employees) due in next month. For example, In January we should be able to see the February Milestone achievers.

Milestone achievers means "Employees who will complete 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40 and so on" years in company in next month.

Can anyone please assist?

Thank you so much in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have a table `employees` with a `hired_at` column, containing the date, when they began working in the company, you just have to get the rows where the difference between next month and their hire date is a multiple of 60 months (5 years):

```
SELECT employee_name, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE_FORMAT(hired_at, '%Y-%m-01'), DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')) / 60 AS how_many_years
FROM employees
WHERE 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DATE_FORMAT(hired_at, '%Y-%m-01'), DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')) % 60 = 0;
```

I'm using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` with the unit `MONTH` to calculate the difference and `DATE_FORMAT` to set both dates to the first of the month. This may not be necessary, but you're on the safe side with it.

The `% 60 = 0` is the `modulo` operation (`%`). If the previous is dividable through 60 with nothing left (`0`), then we have a multiple of 60 months / 5 years. Just dividing the difference through 60 in the `SELECT` clause will give you how many years the employee is working for the company.

- read more about `timestampdiff` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) and `date_format` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)